# How to change the thumbnail of three different div when click on a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, gallery

I'm relatively new into html, css and javascript. So far, I have a landing page with a thumbnail gallery. For different reasons, every thumbnail is located in a different div. I used javascript to make the thumbnail change when I click inside the div, and the thumbnail changes. The problem is: when I change to another div I need to click two times to make the script start working.
My html and js code is:

```
<div id="thumb1" class="fluid"><img src="img/image2.jpg" img id="img1" alt=""/></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var images = ["img/image1.jpg",
              "img/image2.jpg",
              "img/image3.jpg" 
],

i = 1;
for (var j=images.length; j--;) {
var img = new Image();
img.src = images[j];
}

document.getElementById('img1').addEventListener('click', function() {
this.src = images[i >= images.length - 1 ? i = 0 : ++i];
}, false);
</script>

<div id="thumb2" class="fluid"><img src="img/imageC.jpg" img id="img2" alt=""/></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var images2 = [
"img/imageA.jpg",
"img/imageB.jpg",
"img/imageC.jpg",
"img/imageD.jpg"
],
i = 1;
for (var j=images2.length; j--;) {
var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = images2[j];
}

document.getElementById('img2').addEventListener('click', function() {
this.src = images2[i >= images2.length - 1 ? i = 0 : ++i];
}, false);
</script>
```

Is there a way to convert this two scripts (or more) into only one in a simple an easy way? Right now, the script is the same but I don't feel like duplicating the script each time for every div is the most reasonable way to proceed. Moreover, since I will need more than two div, like nine or ten... I don't want a bunch of useless code...Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: When you need to run an code snippet several times, why not putting it in a function that is called several times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this solution, where you put all your images inside every div, but every time, all the images are hidden except one, and the onClick listener changes the display property.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getOnlyImagesFromArray(nodeList) {
        var onlyImagesArray = [];

        var nodeListAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList, 0);
        nodeListAsArray.forEach( function(element) { 
            if(element.localName == 'img') {
                onlyImagesArray.push(element);
            }
        });

        return onlyImagesArray;  
    }

    function handleClick() {
        // using JQuery here would be much cleaner, but out of shear lazyness, I've created the helper function "getOnlyImagesFromArray"
        var onlyImages = getOnlyImagesFromArray(this.childNodes);

        var visibleIndex = -1;
        for(var i = 0; i < onlyImages.length; i++) {
            if(onlyImages[i].style.display == 'inline') {
                visibleIndex = i;
                break;
            }  
        };

        onlyImages[visibleIndex].style.display = "none";
        onlyImages[visibleIndex >= onlyImages.length - 1 ? visibleIndex = 0 : ++visibleIndex].style.display = "inline";
    }
</script>


<div id="thumb1" class="fluid">
    <img src="img/image1.jpg" img id="img1" alt="" style="display:none"/>
    <img src="img/image2.jpg" img id="img1" alt="" style="display:inline"/>
    <img src="img/image3.jpg" img id="img1" alt="" style="display:none"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('thumb1').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
</script>

<div id="thumb2" class="fluid">
    <img src="img/imageA.jpg" img id="img2" alt="" style="display:none"/>
    <img src="img/imageB.jpg" img id="img2" alt="" style="display:none"/>
    <img src="img/imageC.jpg" img id="img2" alt="" style="display:inline"/>
    <img src="img/imageD.jpg" img id="img2" alt="" style="display:none"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('thumb2').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm! And a much more elegant solution than all the useless lines of code I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you use `var` inside an inline script, it always create it in main scope (i.e. `window`).

e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 1;

  //...your code
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 2;

  //...your code
</script>
```

Both scripts assign value into `window.i` which will be equal to 2 in both scripts.

To make it separate, wrap each script into a function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var i = 1;

        //...your code
    })();      
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var i = 2;

        //...your code
    })();      
</script>
```

Or simple instead of `i` use something more specific, e.g. `imageIndex1` and `imageIndex2`.

---

More experienced developers may write it like this, which is a bit shorter but less readable for beginners:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i) {
        //...your code
    })(1);      
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i) {
        //...your code
    })(2);      
</script>
```